# Number partition subjected to the cardinality of subset

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, number-theory

I hope someone can take some time to consider the following problem and welcome to discuss together.

[Number partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) is one of well-known NP-hard problems.

Now I am considering the hardness of constrained partition problem. In particular, [the cardinality of multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) $S$ is n, denoted by $|S|=n$. Now is it NP-completeness to determine whether a given multiset $S$ of positive integers can be partitioned into two subsets $S_1$ and $S_2$ such that the sum of the numbers in $S_1$ equals the sum of the numbers in S2, and subjected to the cardinality of sub multiset $S_1$ is equals $k$, that is $|S_1|=k$ where $k <= n$

Comment: Did you try the reduction from Number partition problem?

Comment: Intuitively, i think the constrained number partition is harder than that original one

Comment: You are right! For a formal proof, try to show a polynomial-time reduction from the Number partition problem to the constrained number partition problem. It is not that difficult.